# Refactor complex FlagsAttribute bitwise check

Tags: c#, .net, enums, bitwise-operators

Apologies if this has been asked before; I'm even struggling with the correct terminology to define the problem/goal.

I have `Person` objects...

```
public class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public HeroAbilities Abilities { get; set; }
    public SuperHero Hero { get; set; }
}
```

... where each `Person` has a range of abilities that makes them potential superheroes:

```
[FlagsAttribute()]
public enum HeroAbilities : long
{
    None = 0,
    Strong = 1,
    Fly = 2,
    WarpSpeed = 4,
    Crazy = 8
}
```

Once I know what their abilities are, I can make them an appropriate hero:

```
public class SuperHero
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

For example, here is how I declare two `Person` objects, and check each one:

```
// Simple check: person should travel at warp speed
var p1 = new Person() { FullName = "Barry Allen", Abilities = HeroAbilities.Strong | HeroAbilities.WarpSpeed };
if(p1.Abilities.HasFlag(HeroAbilities.WarpSpeed))
{
    p1.Hero = new SuperHero() { Name = "The Flash" };
}

// Complex check: person should either be crazy, or be strong AND can fly
var p2 = new Person() { FullName = "Mr F. Bar", Abilities = HeroAbilities.None };
if (p2.Abilities.HasFlag(HeroAbilities.Crazy) || p2.Abilities.HasFlag(HeroAbilities.Strong) && p2.Abilities.HasFlag(HeroAbilities.Fly))
{
    p2.Hero = new SuperHero() { Name = "SuperFooB" };
}
```

The goal is to take the logic that checks whether a `Person` is suitable to be that hero, and place it within each respective `SuperHero` class, so I can do something like this:

```
var sh = new SuperHero() { ... };
var p = new Person() { .... };
if(sh.PersonSuitable(p)) { p.Hero = sh };
```

The part I'm really struggling with is that some checks are complex (e.g. `X or (Y and Z)`), so `[Enum.HasFlag][1]` doesn't suffice.  I'm at the limit of my rather limited OOP experience, so perhaps missing something simple.

Comment: A simple way to unravel it is to add properties to the class.  Like IsStrong, CanFly, HasWarpSpeed, IsCrazy.  The property getters are just one-liners and the if statements get to be a lot more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting problem indeed! IMHO you can create Super Hero Profile here which would define set of abilities and association to one of the instances of the Super Hero class. Once defined you should be able to intercept it with the person abilities and detect the perfect match, but remember you might end up with more then one match indeed )).

Disclaimer: the code may not perform as expected since it was put together to visualize the conceptual solution to the problem only.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject4
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest2
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var superHeroFactory = new SuperHeroFactory();

            var p1 = new Person {FullName = "Barry Allen", Abilities = {new Strong(), new WarpSpeed()}};
            p1.Hero = superHeroFactory.Create(p1);

            var p2 = new Person {FullName = "Mr F. Bar", Abilities = {new Crazy(), new Strong(), new CanFly()}};
            p2.Hero = superHeroFactory.Create(p2);
        }
    }

    public class SuperHeroFactory
    {
        private readonly List<Tuple<SuperHero, List<Ability>>> _profiles =
            new List<Tuple<SuperHero, List<Ability>>>
            {
                new Tuple<SuperHero, List<Ability>>(
                    new SuperHero {Name = "The Flash"}, new List<Ability> {new WarpSpeed()}),
                new Tuple<SuperHero, List<Ability>>(
                    new SuperHero {Name = "SuperFooB"}, new List<Ability> {new Crazy()}),
                new Tuple<SuperHero, List<Ability>>(
                    new SuperHero {Name = "SuperFooB"}, new List<Ability> {new Strong(), new CanFly()})
            };

        public SuperHero Create(Person person)
        {
            // you may end up with more then one match here ))..

            return _profiles.FirstOrDefault(
                profile => !person.Abilities.Except(profile.Item2).Any())?.Item1;
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Ability> Abilities { get; } = new List<Ability>();
        public SuperHero Hero { get; set; }
    }

    public class SuperHero
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Ability { }
    public class Strong : Ability { }
    public class CanFly : Ability { }
    public class WarpSpeed : Ability { }
    public class Crazy : Ability { }
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you, that's interesting (based on my limited understanding).  So we're losing the `enum` and replacing with a class for each ability?

Comment: Just as one of the possible alternatives, yes. If you like enums more you might consider grouping different enum variations into profiles, it will just change the init and query part to check for the flags instead. But essentially give you more dynamic way of managing permutations of the abilities.